# How to read current db version number in dexie?

Tags: javascript, caching, indexeddb, dexie

In [Dexie](http://dexie.org/), when you need to upgrade your schemas or table architectures, you use [`db.version(X)`](http://dexie.org/docs/Dexie/Dexie.version()) method.

The library will then check whether the user's browser has a previous version cached and do the appropriate upgrade steps.

But I cannot find how to read the current user's *db version* manually.

So for example if write this purposefully breaking code:

<s>`db.version(1).stores(/* my schema */)`</s> *// remove this code* 
`db.version(2).stores(/* my schema */)`

The library will politely throw an error saying that the version the user currently has (obviously, `1`) has no schema.

But is there a way to read what version *exactly* the user has?

It could be useful for debugging!

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to skip the whole `version()` thing if you only want to inspect the database. For instance, I'm able to print the version number of my database by using this code.

```
new Dexie("myDB").open().then((db) => console.log(db.verno))
```

Note that (as stated in the documentation), Dexie multiples the version number set through `.version()` by 10 so if you inspect the database in your browser's debugger you will see a number which is 10 times the number you get from using the [`verno` field](http://dexie.org/docs/Dexie/Dexie.verno.html).

Answer (score 3):

In Dexie version 3+. You can use:

- `Dexie.verno`: to get the dexie version. The dexie version is the highest value of the registered versions.
- `Dexie.idbdb.version`: to get the native version of the `IndexedDB`. It's the `Dexie.verno` multipled by `10`. See [here](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/issues/59) for more technical explanation.

```js
const db = new Dexie("AppDB");

db.version(1);
db.version(2);
db.version(5);

db.open();

db.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(db.verno); // 5
  console.log(db.idbdb.version); // 50
});
```